# Scrollbar in tkinter tab doesnt work as it should. Scrollbar is on the bottom of my gui app instead ov covering whole tab

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

Scrollbar is on the bottom of my app instead of covering the whole tab, in fact scrollbar doesn't work. What should I change?

I made this app in tkinter, but it doesn't look like I would like it to be. 
Code under shows how does it look like, and in the link I put screen of my app

```
import tkinter as tk    
from tkinter import ttk    
from tkinter import scrolledtext    
from tkinter import Menu    
from functools import partial    
from math import sqrt, erfc, pi    
from scipy.integrate import quad  ## funkcja calkujaca    
import numpy as np    
from matplotlib import cm    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D    

win = tk.Tk()    


win.title("Aplikacja do projektowania")    

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(win)  # Create Tab Control    

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)  # Create a tab    
tabControl.add(tab1, text='Obliczenia poglądowe')  # Add the tab    
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)  # Add a second tab    
tabControl.add(tab2, text='Obliczenia zaawansowane')  # Make second tab     visible    

tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")  # Pack to make visible    


dane = ttk.LabelFrame(tab1, text=' Wstaw dane ')    
dane.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=8, pady=2)    
dane2 = ttk.LabelFrame(tab2, text=' Wartości: ')    
dane2.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=4)    


dane2 = ttk.LabelFrame(tab2, text=' Wartości: ')    
dane2.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=4)
```

i guess problem is made by code below, but i have no idea how to change it

```
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(win)    
scrollbar.pack(side = tk.RIGHT, fill = tk.Y)             
scrollbar.config(command = dane2.config)



a0_label = ttk.Label(dane2, text="   ")    
a0_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='W')    
a1_label = ttk.Label(dane2, text="Maksymalne godzinowe obciążenie gruntu: [W] ")    
a1_label.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='W')    

win.mainloop()
```

I would be very grateful if someone knows what to do with this error

picture of how does it look:

[image: picture of how does it look]

Answer (score 1):

You're telling tkinter to pack tabControl and use all available space. Create and pack the scrollbar before packing tabControl, so that the space you want the scrollbar to use is not available.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Aplikacja do projektowania")
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(win)  # Create Tab Control
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)  # Create a tab
tabControl.add(tab1, text='Obliczenia poglądowe')  # Add the tab
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)  # Add a second tab
tabControl.add(tab2, text='Obliczenia zaawansowane')  # Make second tab visible

# Packing the scrollbar before the tabControl
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(win)
scrollbar.pack(side = tk.RIGHT, fill = tk.Y)

tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")  # Pack to make visible
dane = ttk.LabelFrame(tab1, text=' Wstaw dane ')
dane.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=8, pady=2)
dane2 = ttk.LabelFrame(tab2, text=' Wartości: ')
dane2.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=4)
dane2 = ttk.LabelFrame(tab2, text=' Wartości: ')
dane2.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=4)
a0_label = ttk.Label(dane2, text="   ")
a0_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='W')
a1_label = ttk.Label(dane2, text="Maksymalne godzinowe obciążenie gruntu: [W] ")
a1_label.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='W')
scrollbar.config(command = dane2.config)

win.mainloop()
```

[image: New window]

Comment: thank you for your answer it helps a lot, but scrollbar still doesn"t work correctly. Even if i use this scrollbar it doesn't move my app  up/down

Comment: @MaciekGładysz You need to add a yscrollcommand-hook (yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set) to whatever you want to scroll and fix the scrollbar.config so that the scrollbar nows what to control, see the first example here http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm

Comment: Also note the comment about supported widgets on the link: "The Scrollbar widget is almost always used in conjunction with a Listbox, Canvas, or Text widget. Horizontal scrollbars can also be used with the Entry widget."

Comment: Ok thank you very much, it helps a lot. But i have found that the labelframes are not supporting scrolling, so if someone have the same problem as i - here is the answer, you can't make it that way